# Modulus and Exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The question:

> Determine $N$ where $0$ $\leq$ $n$ $\leq$ $16$ such that $710^{447}$$\equiv$ $n$ $($ mod $17$ $)$

**My attempt**

> $710^{1}$ $\equiv$ $710$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $13$
>
> $710^{2}$ $\equiv$ $13^{2}$ $\equiv$ $169$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $16$
>
> $710^{3}$ $\equiv$ $16*13$ $\equiv$ $208$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $4$
>
> $710^{4}$ $\equiv$ $16^{2}$ $\equiv$ $256$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $1$
>
> $710^{5}$ $\equiv$ $16^{2}*13$ $\equiv$ $3328$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $13$
>
> $710^{6}$ $\equiv$ $4^{2}$ $\equiv$ $16$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $16$
>
> $710^{7}$ $\equiv$ $16*4*13$ $\equiv$ $832$ (mod $17$) $\equiv$ $16$

It follows,

$$710^{3(149)}\equiv4^{148+1}\equiv4^{148}*4^{1}\equiv4^{2(74)}
*4^{1}$$
$$4^{2(74)}*4^{1}\equiv4^{8}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}*4^{1}$$

$$65536 (mod 17) \equiv 1$$

So,

$$4^{8}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}*4^{5(7)}\equiv4^{140}$$

And,

$$4^{140}\equiv4^{4*5*7}$$

Since $$4^{4}=256$$

We obtain $$256 (mod 17) \equiv 1$$

and, $$1^{5*7}=1$$

Thus, $N$=$1$

Comment: I expanded $4^{2(74)}$ and $4^{2}*4^{2}*4^{2}*4^{2}$.

Comment: The $4^{8}$ cancels out, since it's modulus is 1 when we substitute. $4^{8}$ mod $17$ $=$ $1$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the only problem is the single missing factor of 4.

Comment: Haha I'm off by a **whole** factor of $4$. I don't really see where, can you point it out? I'm confused by my own work *laughs nervously*...

Comment: Once you get $710^4 \equiv 1 \mod 17$ you are soooooooo golden!.  That means  $710^{447} = (710)^4*(710)^4*..............*(710)^4*710^3 \equiv 1*1*1*......*1*4\equiv 4 \mod 17$.  Don't *bother* with any higher powers (actually that's always good advice).

Comment: So. What *does* $N$ equal? And yeah, I realize I did more calculations (albeit incorrect ones) than necessary.

Comment: As soon as you had $710^4\equiv 1 \bmod 17$ you can reduce any other $710^a$ with $a>4$ to  $710^a\equiv 710^{(a-4)}\cdot 710^4\equiv 710^{(a-4)} \bmod 17$, and so step down incrementally into known values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know Fermats Little theorem that states if $p$ is prime (as $17$ is) and $a\not \equiv 0 \mod p$ then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$.

So $710^{447}= 710^{16k + m} \equiv 710^{16k}710^m \equiv 710^m \mod 17$.

If not:

$710 = 41*17 + 13 \equiv 13\equiv -4 \mod 17$. ($4$ is a much nicer number than $13$).

$710^2 \equiv (-4)^2 = 16 \equiv -1 \mod 17$. ($1$ is as nice as you can get.)

$710^4 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 17$.

$710^{444} = (710^4)^{111} \equiv 1^{111}\equiv 1 \mod 17$.

So $710^{447}\equiv 1*710^3 \equiv (-4)^3 \equiv (-4)^2*(-4)\equiv (-1)*(-4) \equiv 4 \mod 17$.

But, yes, what you did looks okay but there's an error somewhere.

....

Once your realize that $710^4 \equiv 1 \mod 17$ it may, or may not, be worth noting that $710^{4k} \equiv 1 \mod 17; 710^{4k + 1} \equiv 13 \mod 17; 710^{4k +2} \equiv 16 \mod 17; 710^{4k + 3}\equiv 4 \mod 17$.  And that is *all* of the congruences

Comment: I am aware of Fermat's Little Thm. and its results, but I don't think my professor would like that...he's a bit of a stickler in that way, I guess. And I didn't see the application for this, until now. Good intuition. Now I need to *really* analyze exactly what you did...

Comment: Well, all I did was take powers of $(-4)$ until I got $(-4)^4 \equiv 1 \mod 17$.  And that lets me say $(-4)^{4k}\equiv 1 \mod 17$.  So $447  = 444 + 3$ so $(-4)^{447}\equiv (-4)^{3} \mod 17$.

Comment: Basically I did what you did but I was a bit more focused.

Comment: Also, you were more efficient. Good work. I see you around MSE a lot...

Comment: Yuck.  What is k and m?

Comment: k and m are anything you darned well want them to be.  If the raise (710) to any power it will have one of four values depending on what the power is modulo 4.  I.e.  if $n=4*k +m $ for any $n $, then $710^n\equiv (-4)^m $ which is $1,13,16,4$ depending on if $m=0,1,2$ or $3$.

Comment: So $710^{5,678,937,521}\equiv 13\mod 17$ because $5,678,937,521\equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

710 = 41 * 17 + 13 = 42 * 17 - 4
447 = 27 * 16 + 15

As 710 /= 0 (mod 17), by Fermat's little theorem
710^16 = 1 (mod 17).

Thus 710^447 = (-4)^15 (mod 17)

-4 * (-4)^15 = 1 (mod 17);  -4 * 4 = 1 (mod 17)
(-4)^15 = 4 (mod 17) since $Z_{17}$ is a field.

710^447 = 4 (mod 17)

Answer (score 0):

If you have $710^4=1$ mod $17$ it implies that $710^{4n}=1$ mod $17$, since $447=444+3=4(111)+3$, you deduce that $710^{447}=710^3$ mod $17= 3$ mod $17$.

Comment: How do you know that is the correct mod? That is a ridiculous computation (I am speaking about $710^{4}$) How can we simplify this better?

Comment: If $710^4=1$ mod $17$, $710^8=710^4\times 710^4 =1\times 1$ mod $17$ and $710^{4n}=1$ mod $17$.

Comment: I can get more on board with this

Answer (score 0):

Once you have $710^{447} \equiv 4^{149}\equiv 4^{2(74)}\times 4$, 
note that $4^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$

Your work is fine except that you lost a factor of 4 after "So,". You went from considering $4^{149}$ in the previous paragraph to considering $4^{148}$ in the rest of your work.

As you note in your scratchwork, $n^a\times n^b = n^{a+b}$ and $(n^{a})^{b} \equiv n^{ab}$

Hint: Since $4^2 = 16 \equiv -1\pmod {17}$ Then $4^{2(74)} \equiv (4^{2})^{74}\equiv (-1)^{74}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Ah. I imagined it was a silly algebra mistake.